# python script for api call

Tags: python, rest, api

I a splunk developer need to create a python script to get data from website using api call. I have no idea about how to write python script.

I have one refresh token through which we will get another token (access token ).

```
curl -X POST https://xxxx.com/api/auth/refreshToken   -d <refresh token>
```

above command will return only access code in text format

```
curl -X GET https://xxxx.com/api/reporting/v0.1.0/training -g --header "Authorization:Bearer <access token>"| json_pp
```

by running above code we will get the data in json format.

I need to create a python script for this type api call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a library in python to work with HTTP requests https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/
It should allow you to do all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a file called rest.py, then :

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json

# Replace with the correct URL
url = "http://api_url"

# It is a good practice not to hardcode the credentials. So ask the user to enter credentials at runtime
myResponse = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)
#print (myResponse.status_code)

# For successful API call, response code will be 200 (OK)
if(myResponse.ok):

    # Loading the response data into a dict variable
    # json.loads takes in only binary or string variables so using content to fetch binary content
    # Loads (Load String) takes a Json file and converts into python data structure (dict or list, depending on JSON)
    jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)

    print("The response contains {0} properties".format(len(jData)))
    print("\n")
    for key in jData:
        print key + " : " + jData[key]
else:
  # If response code is not ok (200), print the resulting http error code with description
    myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: need to implement JWT Authorization in python.
your code work for api call having basic authorisation(username and password).